# Zoomming uiscrollview that contain another uiscrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a uiScroll view (superview) that contain another uiScrollview as it subview.

The zooming gesture of the super view is working when at least 1 touch point is outside the subview 
But when 2 touch point is inside the subview, zooming of superview is not working.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need only the superview zooming?

Comment: I have  another action that enable zooming for the subview, normally i jus need zoom for the superview.

Comment: Then you must subclass your scrollView and pass the touch events, I can provide some code if you want

Answer (score 0):

You need subclass your scrollView and allow pass the touch events, you need to use this class in your inner scrollView

## .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SwipeableScrollView : UIScrollView

@end
```

## .m

```
#import "SwipeableScrollView.h"

@implementation SwipeableScrollView


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.superview touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.superview touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.superview touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

Hope this helps